# PHP GD imagejpeg: output file size is bigger size than original

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, image-manipulation, gimp

The following script is supposed to create an image with lower quality and so smaller file size (kb), instead it create an image with lower quality but bigger file size.

On my test the original is about 300kb, using 90% quality the output is almost the double and using 100% quality, the output is more than 1mb ...

```
<?php

$quality = 90;
$path = '/var/www/TEST/';
$inputSrc = $path . 'original.jpg';
$outputSrc = $path . 'after' . $quality . '.jpg';

$handler = imagecreatefromjpeg($inputSrc);
imagejpeg($handler, $outputSrc, $quality);
```

I assume the issue is related to `imagejpeg` bad implementation ...

- is there any way to workaround this ?
- is`ImageMagick`a better solution ?

Thanks

**Update**

I was curious so I gave a try to `ImageMagick` and unfortunately I have similar result (slightly better).

**Full test results:**

Original size: 294.6Kb

- *GD (imagejpeg)* 90%: 581.7Kb
- *GD (imagejpeg)* 100%: 1.1Mb
- *ImageMagick* 90%: 431.7Kb
- *ImageMagick* 100%: 780.9kb

**Update 2**

I did some more test with GIMP and looks that in order to obtain a file with very similar size to the original one you have to check the option `use quality setting from original image`.

Now I'm confused more ... since when I select that setting Gimp automatically change the output quality to 74% (for the example image).
I was assuming that the JPEG quality value, if lower that 100%, decrease the image quality at every iteration of a save ... but I start to think I'm wrong here.

**Update 3**

With `ImageMagick` is not necessary to specify the quality of the sample and if you leave it empty`ImageMagick` will use the same quality detected in the input image.
So for the example image it is detected as a quality of 69 and the outfile is **326kb**. That is the best result so far.

Here the image I'm using:

[image]

Comment: You could lower your jpeg quality from `90` to `75` (or even lower), and if you have access to ImageMagick it is a wonderful tool!

Comment: Agreed with the above comment, the issue is with `90`, that is probably the issue.

Comment: come on, if I reduce the image quality I should get a smaller file size 
.. and in the same way if I use 100 of quality I should get the same file size, instead I get an image 4 time bigger

Comment: How about posting the image?

Comment: Done. I have also tested imageMagik

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I start to think you are right here. see my `update 2`

Comment: @WonderLand did you manage to find a clear answer.. I have the same issue using GD but I did not find a clean answer

Answer (score 3):

I had a little look at this. You can work backwards in ImageMagick and, rather than define the quality and see what size results, you can define the size and see what quality results. So, for a concrete example, you can say you want the output file not to exceed 100kB, like this:

```
convert MShRR.jpg -define jpeg:extent=100k out.jpg
```

and you get 99kB like this:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff    294608 14 Jan 09:36 MShRR.jpg
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff     99989 14 Jan 09:44 out.jpg
```

To my eyes, the resulting image is a little posterised:

[image]

You can often add a tiny amount of blur to disguise this, as follows:

```
convert MShRR.jpg -blur x0.5 -define jpeg:extent=100k out.jpg
```

[image]

YMMV - Your Mileage May Vary !!!

Comment: I'm a bit confused, maybe because I'm not very into image manipulation ... is it not possible to open a jpg and re-save it without having a bigger size ?

Comment: Different programs make different decisions as to colour fidelity, image quality, smoothness, sharpness, processing time, file size.

Comment: yes, sure. But If I save 10 time an image and everytime I select quality 70% ... every saved file will have 30% less quality ? From what I understand no